# Epslatex terminal in gnuplot labels out of screen

Tags: gnuplot, label

I'm plotting a dataset in gnuplot's epslatex terminal. the code is the one below

```
set terminal epslatex color colortext standalone font 10 header \
'\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, mathtools, breqn, amsthm, mathrsfs}' 
set out 'fit.tex'



set key top right box height 0.3
unset border 
set style line 123 dt 2 lc 'gray'
set grid linestyle 123


##----->LABELS##
set title '$\ln{\left(\dfrac{P}{P_0}\right)}$ vs $\dfrac{1}{T}$' 
set xlabel '$\dfrac{1}{T}$ (K$^{-1}$)' 
set ylabel '$\ln{\left(\dfrac{P}{P_0}\right)}$' 


##----->FIT##
f(x) = m * x + q
fit f(x) 'asc.txt' u 1:2:3:4 xyerrors via m, q

##----->PLOT##
p 'asc.txt' u 1:2:3:4 w xyerrorbars t 'data', f(x) t 'Fit'
set out
```

And the output that i get is the one below

[image: plot]

As you can see the labels are out of the canvas. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes gnuplot fails to estimate the width or height of text elements. You can manually increase the space for the labels on the left side and on bottom:

```
set lmargin at screen 0.17
set bmargin at screen 0.17
```

Play with the numbers.

For completeness, also `rmargin` and `tmargin` can be adjusted if necessary.